# Replacing \n while keeping \r\n intact

Tags: python, regex, newline, linefeed

I have a huge CSV file (196244 line) where it has \n in place other than new lines, I want to remove those \n but keep \r\n intact.
I've tried `line.replace` but seems like it is not recognizing `\r\n` so next I tried regex

```
with open(filetoread, "r") as inf:
    with open(filetowrite, "w") as fixed:
        for line in inf:
            line = re.sub("(?<!\r)\n", " ", line)
            fixed.write(line)
```

but it is not keeping `\r\n` it is removing everything. I can't do it in Notepad++ it is crashing on this file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not exposing the line breaks to the regex engine. Also, the line breaks are "normalized" to LF when using `open` with `r` mode, and to keep them all in the input, you can read the file in in the binary mode using `b`. Then, you need to remember to also use the `b` prefix with the regex pattern and replacement.

You can use

```py
with open(filetoread, "rb") as inf:
    with open(filetowrite, "wb") as fixed:
        fixed.write(re.sub(b"(?<!\r)\n", b" ", inf.read()))
```

Now, the whole file will be read into a single string (with `inf.read()`) and the line breaks will be matched, and eventually replaced.

Pay attention to

- `"rb"` when reading file in
- `"wb"` to write file out
- `re.sub(b"(?<!\r)\n", b" ", inf.read())` contains `b` prefixes with string literals, and `inf.read()` reads in the file contents into single variable.

Comment: This is replacing everything \n and \r\n I want to get rid of \n only

Comment: @Lisa I updated with the tested code.

Answer (score 3):

When you open a file with a naive [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) call, it will load a view of the file with a variety of newlines to be simply `\n` via [`TextIOWrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper)

Explicitly setting `newline="\r\n"` should allow you to read and write the newlines the way you expect

```py
with open(path_src, newline="\r\n") as fh_src:
    with open(path_dest, "w", newline="\r\n") as fh_dest:
        for line in fh_src:  # file-likes are iterable by-lines
            fh_dest.write(line[:-2].replace("\n", " "))
            fh_dest.write("\r\n")
```

content example

```py
>>> with open("test.data", "wb") as fh:
...     fh.write(b"""foo\nbar\r\nbaz\r\n""")
...
14
>>> with open("test.data", newline="\r\n") as fh:
...     for line in fh:
...         print(repr(line))
...
'foo\nbar\r\n'
'baz\r\n'
```